# AWS direct connection - multiple subnets from datacenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, vlan, bgp

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get the datacenter subnets to talk to aws via direct connect using BGP. Below is the setup.
Datacenter Router - **Cisco ASR 1001-hx**

**Datacenter subnets**
VLAN 10 - 10.100.0.0/24
VLAN 20 - 10.200.0.0/24
**AWS subnets**
10.0.0.0/16

For the AWS direct I'm using 10.90.0.0/29 subnet in VLAN 90 for the virtual interfaces.
AWS vif ip - 10.90.0.1
Datacenter cisco sub-interface - 10.90.0.2

I've added 10.90.0.1 as a bgp neighbor with ASN and all that works fine. I can ping the AWS resources from a linux box having 10.90.0.3 to 10.0.0.33.
But now the question is how do I get the other vlans to talk to the AWS resources? Say from VLAN 10 - 10.100.0.0/24 to ping 10.0.0.33 in aws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you advertise your on-premise subnets (VLAN10/VLAN20) to AWS so the VPC route table gets the proper routes. Make sure also your route on-premise has the correct routes to redirect traffic coming from AWS VPC.